# Button появляется в BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-fragment, material-design, android-button

создал `BottomTabActivity` и один фрагмент с xml файлом. Соединил все это и при создании обычной кнопки в xml файле фрагмента она появляется в этом BottomTab, где бы я ее не распологал. Не знаю в чем беда. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 MainActivity.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


  MainActivity.class



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                  account account = new account();
                FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.navigation, account, account.getTag()).commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:

                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_notifications:

                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
}
```

}

Comment: Пока не пришли телепаты, определяющие проблему по скриншоту, приложите к вопросу код разметки

Comment: приложил страницу с разметкой MainAcivity

Comment: А код фрагмента? Подозреваю там у кнопки констрейнт к дну парента, и это фрагмент с прозрачным фоном попросту НАД навигейшн вью

Comment: В таком случае в активтити надо создать лейаут контейнер, FrameLayout, например, ограничить его сверху, справа и слева по паренту, снизу по боттом навигейшн и в него класть фрагмент

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Проблема заключается в следующем**

А именно в строчке:

```
manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.navigation, account, account.getTag()).commit();
```

Вы наполняете контейнер `R.id.navigation` вашим фрагментом, который содержит эту кнопку. Так как `BottomNavigationView` является наследником `FrameLayout`, он без проблем размещает в себе ваш фрагмент с кнопкой.

**Решение**

В `MainActivity.xml` разместите контейнер для ваших фрагментов `FrameLayout` на одном уровне с `BottomNavigationView`. Допустим, пусть у контейнера будет указан атрибут `android:id="@+id/container"`.

Тогда в коде измените проблемную строку на:

```
manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, account, account.getTag()).commit();
```